# Move animation from one jsfiddle to another

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

I made a small scale experiment where I was testing an animation that would happen when you repeatedly hit the yellow square, in the jsfiddle below:

http://jsfiddle.net/aritro33/v86tE/5/

However, I am trying to move the animation seen in that jsfiddle to the jsfiddle here when you hit the compose/post circle/button. The animation would be applied to the posts. This is the jsfiddle:

I am having problems however, and after the 3+ times hitting the compose and post button, the animation falls apart.

Any ideas how to put the same animation seen in the first jsfiddle in the second jsfiddle for the posts?

Thanks so much to anyone who can help!

HTML for second experiment:

```
<div id="compose"><span id="firstspan">Compose</span>
 <span id="fourthspan">Post</span>

</div>
<span id="noposts">- No Posts Yet -</span>

<div id="composeheader">
    <input type="text" id="secondspan" value="Write Header Here:" />
</div>
<div id="thecolor"></div>
<div class="bubble">
    <input type="text" id="thehex" value="#2AC0A3" />
</div>
<div id="body"><span id="thirdspan" contenteditable="true">Write context text here:</span>

</div>
<ul id="allposts"></ul>
```

CSS for second experiment:

```
 @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100);
 body {
     background-color: #2D3E50;
 }

 #compose {
     height: 215px;
     width: 215px;
     background-color: #EBF1F1;
     border-radius: 150px;
     position: relative;
     left: 100px;
     top: 40px;
     color: #2c3e50;
     -webkit-transition: all 0.15s linear;
     -moz-transition: all 0.15s linear;
     transition: all 0.15s linear;
 }
 #compose:hover {
     background-color: #219B86;
     color: #EBF1F1;
 }
 #firstspan {
     font-size: 39px;
     font-family:'Roboto';
     position: relative;
     left: 22px;
     top: 75px;
 }
 #composeheader {
     height: 80px;
     width: 500px;
     background-color:#2AC0A3;
     position: relative;
     bottom: 175px;
     left: 365px;
     color: white;
 }
 #secondspan {
     color: white;
     font-family:'Roboto';
     font-size: 40px;
     position: relative;
     background-color: #2AC0A3;
     border: 1px solid #2AC0A3;
     left: 15px;
     top: 10px;
 }
 #body {
     min-height: 80px;
     overflow: hidden;
     width: 500px;
     background-color: #C6EEE6;
     position: relative;
     left: 365px;
     bottom: 275px;
     padding: 20px;
     -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
     box-sizing: border-box;
     -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
     -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 }
 #thirdspan {
     color: black;
     font-family:'Roboto';
     outline: 0px solid transparent;

 }

.thirdspan2{
     color: black;
     font-family:'Roboto';
     outline: 0px solid transparent;
}

 #thecolor {
     height: 50px;
     width: 50px;
     background-color: #2AC0A3;
     border-radius: 100px;
     position: relative;
     left: 365px;
     bottom: 315px;
 }
 .bubble {
     position: relative;
     left: 440px;
     bottom: 365px;
     width: 145px;
     height: 50px;
     padding: 0px;
     background: #FFFFFF;
     -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
     -moz-border-radius: 10px;
     border-radius: 10px;
 }
 .bubble:after {
     content:'';
     position: absolute;
     border-style: solid;
     border-width: 10px 15px 10px 0;
     border-color: transparent #FFFFFF;
     display: block;
     width: 0;
     z-index: 1;
     left: -15px;
     top: 15px;
 }
 #thehex {
     font-family:'Roboto';
     font-size: 20px;
     height: 30px;
     width: 115px;
     background-color: white;
     position: relative;
     border: 0px none;
     outline: 0px solid transparent;
     top: 10px;
     left: 28px;
 }
 .animated {
     -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
     -moz-animation-duration: 1s;
     -ms-animation-duration: 1s;
     -o-animation-duration: 1s;
     animation-duration: 1s;
     -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
     -moz-animation-fill-mode: both;
     -ms-animation-fill-mode: both;
     -o-animation-fill-mode: both;
     animation-fill-mode: both;
 }
 .animated.hinge {
     -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
     -moz-animation-duration: 2s;
     -ms-animation-duration: 2s;
     -o-animation-duration: 2s;
     animation-duration: 2s;
 }
 @-webkit-keyframes bounceInDown {
     0% {
         -webkit-transform: translateY(-2000px);
     }
     60% {
         -webkit-transform: translateY(30px);
     }
     80% {
         -webkit-transform: translateY(-10px)
     }
     100% {
         -webkit-transform: translateY()
     }
 }
 @-moz-keyframes bounceInDown {
     0% {
         -moz-transform: translateY(-2000px);
     }
     60% {
         -moz-transform: translateY(30px);
     }
     80% {
         -moz-transform: translateY(-10px)
     }
     100% {
         -moz-transform: translateY()
     }
 }
 @-ms-keyframes bounceInDown {
     0% {
         -ms-transform: translateY(-2000px);
     }
     60% {
         -ms-transform: translateY(30px);
     }
     80% {
         -ms-transform: translateY(-10px)
     }
     100% {
         -ms-transform: translateY()
     }
 }
 @-o-keyframes bounceInDown {
     0% {
         -o-transform: translateY(-2000px);
     }
     60% {
         -o-transform: translateY(30px);
     }
     80% {
         -o-transform: translateY(-10px)
     }
     100% {
         -o-transform: translateY()
     }
 }
 @keyframes bounceInDown {
     0% {
         transform: translateY(-2000px);
     }
     60% {
         transform: translateY(30px);
     }
     80% {
         transform: translateY(-10px)
     }
     100% {
         transform: translateY()
     }
 }
 .bounceInDown {
     -webkit-animation-name: bounceInDown;
     -moz-animation-name: bounceInDown;
     -ms-animation-name: bounceInDown;
     -o-animation-name: bounceInDown;
     animation-name: bounceInDown;
 }
 @-webkit-keyframes bounceInUp {
     0% {
         -webkit-transform: translateY(2000px);
     }
     60% {
         -webkit-transform: translateY(-30px);
     }
     80% {
         -webkit-transform: translateY(10px)
     }
     100% {
         -webkit-transform: translateY()
     }
 }
 @-moz-keyframes bounceInUp {
     0% {
         -moz-transform: translateY(2000px);
     }
     60% {
         -moz-transform: translateY(-30px);
     }
     80% {
         -moz-transform: translateY(10px)
     }
     100% {
         -moz-transform: translateY()
     }
 }
 @-ms-keyframes bounceInUp {
     0% {
         -ms-transform: translateY(2000px);
     }
     60% {
         -ms-transform: translateY(-30px);
     }
     80% {
         -ms-transform: translateY(10px)
     }
     100% {
         -ms-transform: translateY()
     }
 }
 @-o-keyframes bounceInUp {
     0% {
         -o-transform: translateY(2000px);
     }
     60% {
         -o-transform: translateY(-30px);
     }
     80% {
         -o-transform: translateY(10px)
     }
     100% {
         -o-transform: translateY()
     }
 }
 @keyframes bounceInUp {
     0% {
         transform: translateY(2000px);
     }
     60% {
         transform: translateY(-30px);
     }
     80% {
         transform: translateY(10px)
     }
     100% {
         transform: translateY()
     }
 }
 .bounceInUp {
     -webkit-animation-name: bounceInUp;
     -moz-animation-name: bounceInUp;
     -ms-animation-name: bounceInUp;
     -o-animation-name: bounceInUp;
     animation-name: bounceInUp;
 }
 #noposts {
     color: white;
     font-size: 39px;
     font-family:'Roboto';
     position: relative;
     left: 440px;
     bottom: 100px;
 }
 #fourthspan {
     color: #2c3e50;
     font-family:'Roboto';
     font-size: 39px;
     position: relative;
     left: 70px;
     top: 75px;
 }

ul#allposts li{
    min-height: 140px;
    width: 500px;


    position: relative;
    left: 239px;
    bottom: 432px;
}

.thecolor2{

    height: 50px;
width: 50px;
    border-radius: 100px;
background-color: #2AC0A3;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 591px;
    left: 325px;
}

ul{
    list-style-type: none;
}

.composeheader2{
  height: 80px;
     width: 500px;
     background-color:#2AC0A3;
     position: relative;
     bottom: 581px;
     left: 325px;
     color: white;

}

.secondspan2{
      color: white;
     font-family:'Roboto';
     font-size: 40px;
     background-color: #2AC0A3;
     border: 1px solid #2AC0A3;
    position: relative;
         left: 17px;
     top: 13px;

}

.body2{
         min-height: 80px;
     overflow: hidden;
     width: 500px;
     background-color: #C6EEE6;
     position: relative;
     left: 325px;
     bottom: 371px;
     -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
     box-sizing: border-box;
     -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
     -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

JS for second experiment:

```
var clicktwice = false;

var color;
var forrgb;
var finalrgb2;
var myheader;

//198 238 230

//rgb(42, 192, 163) #2AC0A3

//rgb(198, 238, 230) #C6EEE6

//+156, +46, +67

$('#fourthspan').hide();
$('#thecolor').hide();
$('.bubble').hide();
$('#composeheader').hide();
$('#body').hide();

$('#compose').click(function () {

    setInterval(function () {
        $('#noposts').fadeTo(10, 0);
    }, 3000);

});

$("#thehex").keyup(function () {
    color = $("#thehex").val();

    forrgb = $("#thehex").val();
    $("#thecolor").css("background-color", color);
    $("#secondspan").css("background-color", color);
    $("#secondspan").css("border-color", color);
    $("#composeheader").css("background-color", color);
    forrgb = $('#thehex').val().replace('#', '');
    var reg = forrgb.length === 3 ? forrgb[0] + forrgb[0] + forrgb[1] + forrgb[1] + forrgb[2] + forrgb[2] : forrgb;
    var conv = reg.match(/.{2}/g);

    var r = parseInt(conv[0], 16);
    r = r + 156;
    var g = parseInt(conv[1], 16);
    g = g + 46;
    var b = parseInt(conv[2], 16);
    b = b + 67;

    var rgb = r + ',' + g + ',' + b;
    rgb = rgb.replace(/NaN/g, ' ... ');

    var finalrgb = ('rgb(' + rgb + ')');
    finalrgb2 = finalrgb;
    $("#body").css("background-color", finalrgb);

});

$('#compose').click(function () {
    if (clicktwice === false) {
        color = "#2AC0A3";
        finalrgb2 = "rgb(198, 238, 230)";
        $("#secondspan").val("Write Header Here:");
        $('#thirdspan').text("Write context text here:");
                $('#thehex').val(color);
            $("#thecolor").css("background-color", color);
    $("#secondspan").css("background-color", color);
    $("#secondspan").css("border-color", color);
    $("#composeheader").css("background-color", color);
            $("#body").css("background-color", finalrgb2);
         $('#thecolor').fadeTo(0, 1);
        $('#body').fadeTo(0,1);
        $('.bubble').fadeTo(0,1);
        $('#composeheader').fadeTo(0, 1);
        $('#firstspan').hide();
        $('#fourthspan').show();
        $('#thecolor').show();
        $('.bubble').show();
        $('#composeheader').show();
        $('#body').show();

  $(".composeheader2").animate({
    bottom: '-=248px'

  }, 400);

          $(".body2").animate({
    bottom:'-=248px'

  }, 400);

          $(".thecolor2").animate({
    bottom:'-=245px'

  }, 400);

        $('#thecolor').addClass('box animated bounceInDown');
        $('.bubble').addClass('box animated bounceInDown');
        $('#composeheader').addClass('box animated bounceInDown');
        $('#body').addClass('box animated bounceInDown');
        clicktwice = true;
    } else if (clicktwice === true) {

        myheader = $("#secondspan").val();
        $('.bubble').fadeTo(300, 0);
        $('#firstspan').show();
        $('#fourthspan').hide();
        clicktwice = false;
        var thestream = document.getElementById('allposts');

        var oneofpost = document.createElement('li');
        var thecolor2 = document.createElement('div');
        thecolor2.className = "thecolor2";
        var composeheader2 = document.createElement('div');
        composeheader2.className = "composeheader2";
        var secondspan2 = document.createElement('span');
        secondspan2.className = "secondspan2";
        var body2 = document.createElement('div');
        body2.className = "body2";
        var thirdspan2 = document.createElement('span');
        thirdspan2.className = "thirdspan2";




        var bodytext = $('#thirdspan').html();
        thirdspan2.innerHTML = bodytext;
        body2.style.backgroundColor = finalrgb2;
        secondspan2.innerHTML = myheader;
        thecolor2.style.backgroundColor = color;
        composeheader2.style.backgroundColor = color;
        secondspan2.style.backgroundColor = color;
        secondspan2.style.borderColor = color;
        $('#thecolor').fadeTo(0, 0);
        $('#body').fadeTo(0, 0);
        $('#composeheader').fadeTo(0, 0);


        thestream.appendChild(body2);
        thestream.appendChild(thecolor2);

        thestream.appendChild(composeheader2);
        composeheader2.appendChild(secondspan2);
        body2.appendChild(thirdspan2);
            $('#thecolor').removeClass('box animated bounceInDown');
        $('.bubble').removeClass('box animated bounceInDown');
        $('#composeheader').removeClass('box animated bounceInDown');
        $('#body').removeClass('box animated bounceInDown');



    }

});
```

Comment: I don't see any `clearInterval()` in your code, yet you are making a new `setInterval()` on every click.  Does your animation execute exponentially?  This is why.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't quite get what you're trying to tell me -- maybe try attaching a jsfiddle with an answer? @zero298

Comment: Yes, it is -- just wasn't getting the answers I was looking for so I tried again with another jsfiddle attached. @sachleen

Comment: @aritro33 Then edit your previous question.  If you weren't getting relevant answers, you probably did not word your question well enough.  Don't create a new question just because you did not get the right answer fast enough.